# Levelling cabinet base plinth on carpet

Tags: boxes, carcass

I'm planning on building a plinth base for some cabinets that will go on top of carpet (I'm not at the stage for ripping out carpet just yet).

From my experience it can be a little bit fiddly getting things on carpet to be level, so I'm looking for a bit of advice.

[This video from Geoff's joinery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GA27-ZwSLGY&ab_channel=Geoff%27sJoinery) shows the general design I have seen when it comes to plinth bases
[image]

The video uses some kitchen cabinet style plastic adjustable feet, however he does show off some metal ones that would be easier to adjust by drilling a hole through the bottom of any cabinet sat atop it, kind of like Ikea Pax wardrobes:

[image]

I'm just wondering if there was a tried and true method of levelling a plinth like this on carpet?

Comment: Metal feet will definitely work if you can’t bring yourself to cut carpet. You can probably even find little caps for your access holes.

Comment: You can make levelling feet from scratch using common bolts that'll work just fine for this if you want to do this essentially no-cost, and they have the advantage that the contact area of each 'foot' can be absolutely tiny (small enough to be lost in carpet pile). I guess the first thing you should do though is check level in both axes at the proposed site of the cabinets, see how much you need to adjust for.

Comment: FFR, please give context for links included in Qs. Many people won't look at blind links for various reasons (and on mobile may have no way to preview the source or hack one if there's none included). A simple "this video from XXXX" will suffice.

Comment: @Graphus Ive added a bit more to that link description now. Would you be able to show me an example of a DIY levelling foot at all? All I can think of is something like this where I'd have one of those metal threaded doo-dads you hammer into a hole and use my own bolt with the head against the carpet (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adjustable-Levelling-Feet-Toolzia-Furniture/dp/B0B4D7R4TQ/ref=sr_1_32?crid=2MXL9CFBS5H3P&keywords=levelling%2Bfeet&qid=1707299449&sprefix=levelling%2Bfeet%2Caps%2C111&sr=8-32&th=1)

Comment: That "metal threaded doo-dad" is usually called a "T-nut". ;) Also, yes, a T-nut with a bolt threaded into it (head down) is, I believe, _exactly_ what @Graphus is talking about. If you're making the base yourself, you could also drill out for a regular nut, then chisel the round hole to be a hexagon and put a standard nut in there. The flats should hold it, a drop of superglue might help hold it better.

Comment: @FreeMan haha yeah, I found their proper name after a big of Googling :-P I might not have the time/patience to do said chiselling. Screwfix have t-nuts for cheap. I've got some length of threaded rod and I'll check what bolt lengths I have in stock. Might be worth me getting larger M10s in for this as I'll likely need to carve some slots in for a screwdriver etc.

Comment: @FreeMan, given a few factors I'm more a fan of embedding standard nuts into wood than using T-nuts, for any and all applications.

Comment: @FreeMan & graphus - In either way of adding threads to the base... I'm now a little bit concerned about how tall I should actually make this base, given the longest  M8 bolts I've found are from B&Q at about 120mm... Most things I've seen for toekicks (admittedly these are talking about kitchen cabinets) are about 100mm... Be interested in your opinions on that?

Comment: @physicsboy, a hex nut can be surface mounted into a chiselled hex as mentioned (not super easy, but excellent practice), but also by forcing into an undersize hole (measurement across the flats) or epoxied into a clearance hole (measurement corner to corner). Nuts can also be inserted cross-dowel fashion in a mortise/drilled hole/D-shaped mortise (as often used in workbench construction where legs bolt to stretchers). Time constraints and aesthetic preference dictate which to pick. Only two of these methods are remotely as fast as installing a T-nut, but can't beat the price difference :-)

Comment: You're going to need at most 10-12 millimetres of adjustment on one or more of the feel unless your floor is extraordinarily out of flat. So no need to get a super long bolt, just 70mm might be perfect. *"I'd have one of those metal threaded doo-dads you hammer into a hole and use my own bolt with the head against the carpet"* That's absolutely one of the ways you can do this, but you can further minimise the footprint by using the bolt the other way around, with a flat end sharpened by file or grinder to leave a small flat or even a point if you like, which disappear into carpet pile. [contd]

Comment: Obviously you'd never drag anything done this way over the floor, carpet or not!

Comment: *"Would you be able to show me an example of a DIY levelling foot at all?"* While this is a question in its own right, literally Googling exactly that — DIY levelling foot — will give you tons of results (nearly 700k when I tried it just now) that you can do a shallow or deep dive on as you prefer. Perhaps surprisingly there are many different ways these are implemented, some far far beyond the very basic type I had in mind (hex nut embedded in wood with a bolt threaded through).